# What is the impact of enabling Sitecore.Publishing.Recovery.config

Tags: publishing

What is the impact of enabling `Sitecore.Publishing.Recovery.config`?

Our CM environment consists of load-balanced Azure VMs with Azure PaaS for content delivery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a default install of Sitecore the Publishing runs as a `Job`. If IIS or the server is restarted, or the Application Pool for your site is Recycled the publishing task will be terminated, even if the Job did not fully complete. Once your site is brought back online, you would be required to republish in order to complete the operation.

Enabling `Sitecore.Publishing.Recovery.config` will allow for the Publish resume the Publish when the system restarts.

The `initialize` pipeline during application starting up is responsible for kicking off  the `publishRecovery` pipeline, which in turn restarts the publishing.

If you are running multiple CMs then presumably you have a dedicated Publishing Instance set up. This file should only be enabled on that server. Also be sure to select the correct type of `recoveryStrategy` in the config; `FileSystemPublishRecoveryStrategy` which is fine for single instances machines or `DatabasePublishRecoveryStrategy` if you need to take multiple instances (including DR for example) into account.

Also take note of the following note from the config:

> Important: The publishing recovery feature is currently released as an experimental feature.

Answer (score 6):

In the spirit of sharing information, here are two potential issues which could arise from enabling `Sitecore.Publishing.Recovery.config` (I will add more info to this answer in time as and when I learn more about it):

1. If there were a large number of queued publish operations prior to shutdown (which contributed to Sitecore shutting down?) then these would all be resumed when Sitecore re-starts.
2. When publishing resumes after the re-start, there is no built-in way to see the progress of that publish, or even to be aware of it. This could be handled with a module such as this https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Publish_Viewer.aspx or a more basic approach such as this: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/sitecore-job-viewer-see-what-sitecore-is-doing-behind-your-back/

Comment: Good info. With regards to *2)*, that is the same case even if there was no shutdown and multiple users trigger publishes or users close the publish dialog. On SC 8.1.3+ only OOTB tool I can think of is ` /sitecore/admin/Jobs.aspx` to view the jobs.

Comment: I didn't know about the OOTB admin page - good to know!

Comment: I blogged about the new admin tools in 8.1.3/8.2, worth a read if you haven't: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/sitecore-admin-pages-cheat-sheet-new-tools/